# Bitcoin daemon Error: Invalid combination of -regtest and -testnet

Tags: testnet

How to solve above title problem?

I first started with bitcoin as regtest.

Now I want to launch bitcoin as -testnet.

So I did like

root@q352-3023-vps:~/.bitcoin# bitcoind -testnet -daemon

but above error..

Answer (score 2):

So this was because .conf file has line of regtest=1